# Dojo Spinwheel Get Value

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to get the value of a simple SpinWheel using Dojo. The code below prints nothing. If i change "w.get("value")" to "w.value" then I get "Value is undefined" printed. I suspect that the issue is that I should not be using document.getElementById to get my SpinWheelSlot. Is this the incorrect way to do this?

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<title>Dojo SpinWheel</title>
<!-- load Dojo -->
<script src="/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
<script src="/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    "dojox/mobile/parser",
    "dojox/mobile/SpinWheel", 
    "dojox/mobile/View", 
    "dojox/mobile/Heading", 
    "dojox/mobile/SpinWheelSlot", 
    "dijit/registry",
    "dojox/mobile/compat",
    "dojox/mobile"
],
function(registry) {
    showSelectedValue = function(){
            var w = document.getElementById("slot1");
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML =
                "Value is " + w.get("value")
            }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading">
    <span data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ToolBarButton" onClick="showSelectedValue()"     data-dojo-props='label:"OK"'></span>
</div>
    <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading">Custom SpinWheel</h1>
    <div id="spin1" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/SpinWheel" style="width:80px;">
        <div id="slot1" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/SpinWheelSlot"
            labels="A,B,C,D,E"
            style="text-align:center;width:80px;"></div>
    </div>
<p id="msg"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.getElementById is to look up dom element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Above is same as dom.byId() in dojo
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom.html#dojo-dom-byid

> This is a simple alias to document.getElementById, which not only is
>   shorter to write, but fortunately works in all browsers. It turns a
>   domNode reference to some Node byId, or the same node reference if
>   passed a domNode.

To access a dojo widget, use registry.byId()
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html

> dijit/registry stores a collection of all the dijit widgets within a
>   page. It is commonly used to retrieve a reference to a widget from a
>   related piece of data (such as the widget’s DOM node or ID). It
>   contains functions formerly found on the root dijit object for looking
>   up widgets, such as dijit.byId and dijit.byNode.
>
> registry.byId returns the widget that corresponds to the given ID. If
>   no such widget exists, it returns undefined.

Comment: thank you, but when I use registry.byID("slot1") my code stops working all together. Do I need to import anything differently to get registry to work?

Comment: changed something slightly, used registry.byId, everything working. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help. I found my solution.
Actually the fix was pretty simple. I had used id for spinwheel and slot like below..